# Kernel Error screen

Tags: macbook-pro, error, kernel

I have an older Macbook Pro which I haven't used much lately since purchasing a new Macbook Pro. The older one was near capacity and would get very hot. I could still turn it on and look for things now and then until a few weeks ago when turning it on I got the following screen: 
[image]

I have tried doing a 'safe reboot' by holding down the shift key and pressing the power button until the apple logo goes but i continue to get this screen and cannot get into the computer.  Can someone please help me figure out what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`launchd` looks to be failing which is causing this kernel panic. Sadly, not much of a stack trace to work with.

Boot to Recovery (hold Cmd + R at boot) and reinstall OS X from there. The latest version your Mac supports is El Capitan (10.11) but your Recovery partition should allow you to re-install whatever is currently on there.

Don't worry, doing a re-install this way does it in-place so it won't overwrite any of your personal data, just the system files for OS X.

If you get a kernel panic booting to Recovery (both the built in one and Internet Recovery) then there could be a hardware fault and you'll have to either perform diagnostics (you should be able to run the Apple Hardware Test that came on one of your Leopard installation discs) or take it in to Apple for them to check out.